# How to check if a PayPal email address has given the Grant API permission to us?

Tags: paypal

I am a API caller (in adaptive payment), I want to verify if a given email address has granted the API permission to 
process the Refund API off their account.

It would be nice to have an API call to check this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Permissions API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsAbout) which will allow you to explicitly set the third-party API grant and check it.